# Linq query and plain SQL query result differs

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, db2

I trying to run the following DB2 SQL using Entity Framework

```
SELECT CM98.TUCUS01.CUST_NO,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.APPL_DT,   
     CM98.TUUNI30.MDL_ID,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.APPL_ID,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.DLR_NO,   
     CM98.TUMHC07.STAT_CD_DESC_TX,   
     CM98.TUCUS01.LAST_NAME,   
     CM98.TUCUS01.FST_NAME,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.UN_ID,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.PL_ID  
FROM CM98.TUSRV97,   
     CM98.TUMHC06,   
     CM98.TUMHC07,   
     CM98.TUCUS01,   
     CM98.TUUNI30,   
     CM98.TUMHC08  
WHERE ( CM98.TUMHC08.APPL_ID = CM98.TUMHC06.APPL_ID ) and  
     ( CM98.TUMHC07.APPL_STAT_CD = CM98.TUMHC06.APPL_STAT_CD ) and  
     ( CM98.TUUNI30.UN_ID = CM98.TUMHC08.UN_ID ) and  
     ( CM98.TUSRV97.XPROD_DIV_CD = CM98.TUUNI30.XPROD_DIV_CD ) and  
     ( CM98.TUSRV97.XPROD_CD = CM98.TUUNI30.XPROD_CD ) and  
     ( CM98.TUSRV97.MDL_ID = CM98.TUUNI30.MDL_ID ) and  
     ( CM98.TUMHC08.CUST_NO = CM98.TUCUS01.CUST_NO ) and  
( ( "CM98"."TUMHC06"."APPL_STAT_TS" = (SELECT MAX(APPL_STAT_TS) FROM CM98.TUMHC06 WHERE APPL_ID = CM98.TUMHC08.APPL_ID) ) )
```

Below is the Linq query I created,

```
from SRV97 in db.TUSRV97
from MHC06 in db.TUMHC06
from MHC07 in db.TUMHC07
from CUS01 in db.TUCUS01
from UNI30 in db.TUUNI30
from MHC08 in db.TUMHC08
where
 MHC08.APPL_ID == MHC06.APPL_ID &&
 MHC07.APPL_STAT_CD == MHC06.APPL_STAT_CD &&
 UNI30.UN_ID == MHC08.UN_ID &&
 SRV97.XPROD_DIV_CD == UNI30.XPROD_DIV_CD &&
 SRV97.XPROD_CD == UNI30.XPROD_CD &&
 SRV97.MDL_ID == UNI30.MDL_ID &&
 MHC08.CUST_NO == CUS01.CUST_NO &&
 MHC06.APPL_STAT_TS == 
  (from tempTUMHC060 in db.TUMHC06
  where
   tempTUMHC060.APPL_ID == MHC08.APPL_ID
  select new {
   tempTUMHC060.APPL_STAT_TS
  }).Max(p => p.APPL_STAT_TS)
select new {
 CUS01.CUST_NO,
 MHC08.APPL_DT,
 UNI30.MDL_ID,
 MHC08.APPL_ID,
 MHC08.DLR_NO,
 MHC07.STAT_CD_DESC_TX,
 CUS01.LAST_NAME,
 CUS01.FST_NAME,
 MHC08.UN_ID,
 MHC08.PL_ID
}
```

I am getting one row as the result when executing the plain SQL query but nothing when executing Linq query.

**Is the LINQ I have written equivalent to the SQL?**

I don't know what went wrong..Any idea?

**Update :**
Below is the internal query generated by LINQ

```
    {SELECT project1.appl_id 
AS 
  appl_id, project1.cust_no 
AS 
  cust_no, project1.appl_dt 
AS 
  appl_dt, project1.mdl_id1 
AS 
  mdl_id, project1.appl_id1 
AS 
  appl_id1, project1.dlr_no 
AS 
  dlr_no, project1.stat_cd_desc_tx 
AS 
  stat_cd_desc_tx, project1.last_name 
AS 
  last_name, project1.fst_name 
AS 
  fst_name, project1.un_id1 
AS 
  un_id, project1.pl_id 
AS 
  pl_idfrom 
  ( 
             SELECT     extent1.xprod_div_cd    AS xprod_div_cd, 
                        extent1.xprod_cd        AS xprod_cd, 
                        extent1.mdl_id          AS mdl_id, 
                        extent2.appl_id         AS appl_id, 
                        extent2.appl_stat_cd    AS appl_stat_cd, 
                        extent2.appl_stat_ts    AS appl_stat_ts, 
                        extent3.appl_stat_cd    AS appl_stat_cd1, 
                        extent3.stat_cd_desc_tx AS stat_cd_desc_tx, 
                        extent4.last_name       AS last_name, 
                        extent4.fst_name        AS fst_name, 
                        extent4.cust_no         AS cust_no, 
                        extent5.un_id           AS un_id, 
                        extent5.xprod_div_cd    AS xprod_div_cd1, 
                        extent5.xprod_cd        AS xprod_cd1, 
                        extent5.mdl_id          AS mdl_id1, 
                        extent6.appl_id         AS appl_id1, 
                        extent6.un_id           AS un_id1, 
                        extent6.cust_no         AS cust_no1, 
                        extent6.pl_id           AS pl_id, 
                        extent6.dlr_no          AS dlr_no, 
                        extent6.appl_dt         AS appl_dt, 
                        ( 
                               SELECT max(extent7.appl_stat_ts) AS a1 
                               FROM   ( 
                                             SELECT tumhc06.appl_id      AS appl_id, 
                                                    tumhc06.appl_stat_cd AS appl_stat_cd, 
                                                    tumhc06.appl_stat_ts AS appl_stat_ts, 
                                                    tumhc06.cret_by_id   AS cret_by_id 
                                             FROM   honda.tumhc06        AS tumhc06) AS extent7
                               WHERE  extent7.appl_id = extent6.appl_id) AS c1 
             FROM       honda.tusrv97                                    AS extent1 
             CROSS JOIN 
                        ( 
                               SELECT tumhc06.appl_id      AS appl_id, 
                                      tumhc06.appl_stat_cd AS appl_stat_cd, 
                                      tumhc06.appl_stat_ts AS appl_stat_ts, 
                                      tumhc06.cret_by_id   AS cret_by_id 
                               FROM   honda.tumhc06        AS tumhc06) AS extent2 
             CROSS JOIN honda.tumhc07 AS extent3 
             CROSS JOIN 
                        ( 
                               SELECT tucus01.last_name         AS last_name, 
                                      tucus01.fst_name          AS fst_name, 
                                      tucus01.mid_init          AS mid_init, 
                                      tucus01.cust_email_addr   AS cust_email_addr, 
                                      tucus01.cust_state        AS cust_state, 
                                      tucus01.cust_addr         AS cust_addr, 
                                      tucus01.cust_addr2        AS cust_addr2, 
                                      tucus01.cust_city         AS cust_city, 
                                      tucus01.zip_cd5           AS zip_cd5, 
                                      tucus01.zip_cd4           AS zip_cd4, 
                                      tucus01.fips_ctry_cd      AS fips_ctry_cd, 
                                      tucus01.last_upd_date     AS last_upd_date, 
                                      tucus01.cust_no           AS cust_no, 
                                      tucus01.cust_name_sfx_txt AS cust_name_sfx_txt, 
                                      tucus01.zip_cd3           AS zip_cd3, 
                                      tucus01.war_cust_sex_cd   AS war_cust_sex_cd, 
                                      tucus01.cust_typ_cd       AS cust_typ_cd, 
                                      tucus01.cust_ttl_cd       AS cust_ttl_cd, 
                                      tucus01.cust_ttl          AS cust_ttl, 
                                      tucus01.ssec_no           AS ssec_no, 
                                      tucus01.brth_date         AS brth_date, 
                                      tucus01.data_srce_cd      AS data_srce_cd 
                               FROM   cm98.tucus01              AS tucus01) AS extent4 
             CROSS JOIN honda.tuuni30 AS extent5 
             CROSS JOIN honda.tumhc08 AS extent6) 
AS 
  project1where (((((((project1.appl_id1 = project1.appl_id) AND 
  ( 
    project1.appl_stat_cd1 = project1.appl_stat_cd 
  ) 
  ) AND 
  ( 
    project1.un_id = project1.un_id1 
  ) 
  ) AND 
  ( 
    project1.xprod_div_cd = project1.xprod_div_cd1 
  ) 
  ) AND 
  ( 
    project1.xprod_cd = project1.xprod_cd1 
  ) 
  ) AND 
  ( 
    project1.mdl_id = project1.mdl_id1 
  ) 
  ) AND 
  ( 
    project1.cust_no1 = project1.cust_no 
  ) 
  ) AND 
  ( 
    project1.appl_stat_ts = project1.c1 
  )
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the EF is creating exactly the same query? Are you sure both versions are hitting the same database?

Comment: http://www.linqpad.net/ is your friend.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm hitting same database. I have posted the internal query generated by linq..

Comment: You might want to change your Linq to do joins, and really your SQL should too.  At the very lest it should give you easier to understand Linq generated SQL.

Comment: @PaulZahra when I run the above mentioned LINQ query in linqpad I'm getting error "Unable to create a constant value of type 'APP.Models.TUCUS01'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context" but no error when running through visual studio

Comment: Hmm... try http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: Thanks @PaulZahra I already tried that. Linqer generates the same that I have written!. And one more thing, I'm using DB2 provider for connectivity is that anything that cause the LINQ to behave differently?

Comment: Most of the code is straight forward enough... which makes me suspect your nested statement... Instead of select new {tempTUMHC060.APPL_STAT_TS}).Max(p => p.APPL_STAT_TS) try something like OrderBy descending select tempTUMHC060.APPL_STAT_TS).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Tried but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this issue.
Just deleted all the tables from the edmx file and added again, Working as expected.